# Getting selected row of aspgridview when click on link button to get hidden ID value

Tags: gridview, linkbutton

I am binding link button with title data in aspgridview and also binding hidden label which holds the ID value. when user click on this link button I would like to access the ID value. This I need because, if user logs in then only I popup detail window else alert message to login for details.

in lnkTitle_Click() event I am trying to access the selected row to find the label control.

```
GridViewRow grdSelRow = GridView1.SelectedRow;
Label lblID = (Label)grdSelRow.FindControl("lblID");
```

But I am getting grdSelRow as null.

How to get the selected row when click on linkbutton of gridview?

Answer (score 25, accepted):

The problem is that when you click a button in a GridView, the row will only be a Clicked Row and not a `SelectedRow`. If you wanna make it the SelectedRow you have to specify `CommandName="Select"` in the Button's markup.

Here are two methods for accomplish your requirement.

Wiring up an onclick event for the LinkButton inside ItemTemplate

Markup

```
<asp:TemplateField>
    <ItemTemplate>
        <asp:LinkButton ID="LinkButton1" runat="server" 
                    Text="Click1" 
                    OnClick="LinkButton1_Click"/>
    </ItemTemplate>
</asp:TemplateField>
```

Code-behind

```
protected void LinkButton1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    GridViewRow clickedRow = ((LinkButton) sender).NamingContainer as GridViewRow;
    Label lblID = (Label)clickedRow.FindControl("lblID");
}
```

Using RowCommand to catch the LinkButton click.

Markup

```
<asp:TemplateField>
    <ItemTemplate>
        <asp:LinkButton ID="LinkButton2" runat="server" 
                    Text="Click2" 
                    CommandName="MyCustomCommand"/>
    </ItemTemplate>
</asp:TemplateField>
```

Code-behind

```
protected void GridView1_RowCommand(object sender, GridViewCommandEventArgs e)
{
    if(e.CommandName.Equals("MyCustomCommand"))
    {
        GridViewRow clickedRow = ((LinkButton)e.CommandSource).NamingContainer as GridViewRow;
        Label lblID = (Label)clickedRow.FindControl("lblID");
    }
}
```

Comment: +1 @Naveen for specifying "If you wanna make it the SelectedRow you have to specify CommandName="Select" in the Button's markup"

Comment: @Naveen how do you mark selection before you show a javascript confirm in case of gridview?  if i click on cancel in the confirm i do not see the current row selected nor when do i see the selected row before i am shown the confirm popup.

Comment: @dasariramacharanprasad: could you elaborate and ask it as a qiestion. i did not fully understand.

Comment: @naveen How do we mark grid row selection using javascript? Can we call any Asp.net javascript method / or any way to make a row as selected but dont want to perform any action on that button click in that row (since user cancelled in the javascript confirm popup)?